# Using '--filter expression' on Datetime column of DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to filter data from Dynamodb using a column which saves datetime values (like '2021-06-01T06:00:00.255Z'). I tried with the condition --filter-expression "Datecolumn BETWEEN 2021-06-01T12:00:00.000Z AND 2021-06-30T12:00:00.000Z" in aws dynamodb scan query. I'm getting the following error message :

Error Message:
**An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "2021", near: "BETWEEN 2021-"**

Could someone please help me with the query?

Comment: If the date column is of type string, shouldn't the values be quoted?

Comment: Hi @jarmod , I tried with quotes, and enclosing the date column with braces as well but getting the same error.